# How can i set a default value to AspxGridView TimeEdit control

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to set default value current time for AspxGridView TimeEdit control. Is it possible?

KR,

Çağın

Comment: Could you please give us more details about the task.  Actually, it is possible to set the default value for the editor.  Please explain which problem you ran into when doing this.

Comment: I use a aspxgridview and I change a column to TimeEdit. I want to that see "01.12.2011 09:38" (current time) in that TimeEdit area when a user clik to Edit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using the ASPxGridView's [CellEditorInitialize](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CellEditorInitializetopic) event.  Check the value of the e.Column.FieldName property and then set the e.Editor.Value as needed.